# Replace in MySQL without entering MySQL command line?

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

Currently I'm using `mysql -u root -p` and fill the password

and then in MySQL command line, I'm using:

```
use dbname;
update node_revisions set body = replace(body,'textone','texttwo');
```

How can I doing this in terminal without entering MySQL command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy peasy:

```
$ mysql -u root -p dbname -e "update node_revisions set body = replace(body,'textone','texttwo')"
```

Comment: You can also do `mysql -u root -p dbname < file.sql` if you have a bunch of commands you want to run

Answer (score 1):

You can make it so that it won't ask you for the password by creating a file called `.my.cnf` in your home directory, and adding:

```
[client]
host=127.0.0.1
password=<YOUR_PASSWORD>
```

Then you can use the `-e` option to mysql to specify the SQL to execute, for example:

```
mysql -u username -e "update node_revisions set body = replace(body,'textone','texttwo');"
```

This will give you the ability to list the SQL to execute right at the command line and will not ask you for the password for every statement.

Comment: Yep, this is surely an option. Some would argue, though, that, like when using sudo, requiring you to manually enter your password acts as a safety valve of sorts, giving you another couple of seconds to verify mentally if this is the correct command you want to run.